# Logistic Regression with a Neural Network mindset error in computing the cost in the optimization Function

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, math, matrix

The Function below find the best values for parameters W and b where cost (sum of losses) is as much small as possible but when testing the function the matrix costs length does not match
def optimize(w, b, X, Y, num_iterations=200, learning_rate=0.009, print_cost=False):
"""
This function optimizes w and b by running a gradient descent algorithm

```
    Arguments:
    w -- weights, a numpy array of size (num_px * num_px * 3, 1)
    b -- bias, a scalar
    X -- data of shape (num_px * num_px * 3, number of examples)
    Y -- true "label" vector (containing 0 if non-cat, 1 if cat), of shape (1, number of examples)
    num_iterations -- number of iterations of the optimization loop
    learning_rate -- learning rate of the gradient descent update rule
    print_cost -- True to print the loss every 100 steps
    
    Returns:
    params -- dictionary containing the weights w and bias b
    grads -- dictionary containing the gradients of the weights and bias with respect to the cost function
    costs -- list of all the costs computed during the optimization, this will be used to plot the learning curve.
    
    Tips:
    You basically need to write down two steps and iterate through them:
        1) Calculate the cost and the gradient for the current parameters. Use propagate().
        2) Update the parameters using gradient descent rule for w and b.
    """
    
    w = copy.deepcopy(w)
    b = copy.deepcopy(b)
 
    costs = []
    
    
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        # (≈ 1 lines of code)
        # Cost and gradient calculation 
        # grads, cost = ...
        # YOUR CODE STARTS HERE
         grads, cost = propagate(w, b, X, Y)
        
        # YOUR CODE ENDS HERE
        
        # Retrieve derivatives from grads
    dw = grads["dw"]
    db = grads["db"]
        
        # update rule (≈ 2 lines of code)
        # w = ...
        # b = ...
        # YOUR CODE STARTS HERE
    w = w - (learning_rate * dw)
    b = b - (learning_rate * db)
        
        # YOUR CODE ENDS HERE
        
        # Record the costs
    if (i % 100 == 0):
        costs.append(cost)
      
            # Print the cost every 100 training iterations
    if print_cost:
        print ("Cost after iteration %i: %f" %(i, cost))
    
    params = {"w": w,
              "b": b}
    
    grads = {"dw": dw,
             "db": db}
    
    return params, grads, costs
params, grads, costs = optimize(w, b, X, Y, num_iterations=100, learning_rate=0.009, print_cost=False)

print ("w = " + str(params["w"]))
print ("b = " + str(params["b"]))
print ("dw = " + str(grads["dw"]))
print ("db = " + str(grads["db"]))
print("Costs = " + str(costs))

optimize_test(optimize)

AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-3483159b4470> in <module>
      7 print("Costs = " + str(costs))
      8 
----> 9 optimize_test(optimize)

~/work/release/W2A2/public_tests.py in optimize_test(target)
     72 
     73     assert type(costs) == list, "Wrong type for costs. It must be a list"
---> 74     assert len(costs) == 2, f"Wrong length for costs. {len(costs)} != 2"
     75     assert np.allclose(costs, expected_cost), f"Wrong values for costs. {costs} != {expected_cost}"
     76 

AssertionError: Wrong length for costs. 1 != 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer to your question i.e. Why it doesn't work, but I'm just sharing my code that finally worked after a thousand tweakings!
Do Note that all your previous code should be run first and should run successfully!

My Working Code:-

```
# GRADED FUNCTION: optimize
```

def optimize(w, b, X, Y, num_iterations=100, learning_rate=0.009, print_cost=False):
"""
This function optimizes w and b by running a gradient descent algorithm

```
Arguments:
w -- weights, a numpy array of size (num_px * num_px * 3, 1)
b -- bias, a scalar
X -- data of shape (num_px * num_px * 3, number of examples)
Y -- true "label" vector (containing 0 if non-cat, 1 if cat), of shape (1, number of examples)
num_iterations -- number of iterations of the optimization loop
learning_rate -- learning rate of the gradient descent update rule
print_cost -- True to print the loss every 100 steps

Returns:
params -- dictionary containing the weights w and bias b
grads -- dictionary containing the gradients of the weights and bias with respect to the cost function
costs -- list of all the costs computed during the optimization, this will be used to plot the learning curve.

Tips:
You basically need to write down two steps and iterate through them:
    1) Calculate the cost and the gradient for the current parameters. Use propagate().
    2) Update the parameters using gradient descent rule for w and b.
"""

w = copy.deepcopy(w)
b = copy.deepcopy(b)

costs = []

for i in range(num_iterations):
    # (≈ 1 lines of code)
    # Cost and gradient calculation 
    # grads, cost = ...
    # YOUR CODE STARTS HERE
    grads, cost = propagate(w, b, X, Y)
    
    # YOUR CODE ENDS HERE
    
    # Retrieve derivatives from grads
    dw = grads["dw"]
    db = grads["db"]
    
    # update rule (≈ 2 lines of code)
    # w = ...
    # b = ...
    # YOUR CODE STARTS HERE
    w = w - (learning_rate*dw)
    b = b - (learning_rate*db)
    
    # YOUR CODE ENDS HERE
    
    # Record the costs
    if i % 100 == 0:
        costs.append(cost)
    
        # Print the cost every 100 training iterations
        if print_cost:
            print ("Cost after iteration %i: %f" %(i, cost))

params = {"w": w,
          "b": b}

grads = {"dw": dw,
         "db": db}

return params, grads, costs
```

Comment: I don't know why the def part is not appearing in Code mode here!